# iOS device in Organizer is yellow not green

Tags: ios

I am having problems with an iOS device and trying to get an app I'm developing on it. I have tried all the standard restarts, deleting profile from phone, etc. Where would be the first place to start to figure this out?

[image]

Comment: The message is telling you that the version of iOS on your phone is not compatible with that version of Xcode. You need Xcode 4.6.x to use iOS 6.1.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yellow means that your version of XCode (and the SDK) is not the same as your iPhone's version, which is 6.1.3. You need to either update XCode so that you have the latest SDK or restore your device to the version of your SDK. (I don't know how easy it is to do that as I haven't had success with it in the past, but that is what the error message suggests.)

Comment: thx, downloading now - amazing apple doesn't provide better feedback on such a simple issue

Comment: @timpone Actually, the error message says "or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK, which is available here."

Comment: at close 2gb, it's a poor user experience esp in light of the fact that Apple has claimed that they can send diff's now several years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect the device in the mac1 which has xcode 4.6 and then wait for the Xcode to detect the device(green). Then remove the device and connect to the mac2 which has 4.5 now see the device in the organiser it will be green. I don't know the reason but it is working for me. Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not completely correct: there's also a yellow dot, if the device isn't connected to a developer account.
Simply right-click onto the device with that yellow dot and choose "Add to Member center".